# iOS 12.2 Freezes When Adding <audio>

Tags: javascript, ios, audio

I've got a site that loads different activities for language students. Some of the activities involve listening to multiple audio files and answering questions. Since iOS updated to 12.2, these pages crash when trying to write the second audio tag. No errors, just a frozen browser tab. I've replicated a very trimmed down version of the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/a3jyv9c0/3/

That code is only loading 1 audio tag, or you can't get to the page at all. To see it freeze on 12.2, uncomment line 17 and comment line 18. The freeze comes at line 51 when running insertAdjacentHTML. I've tried it a few different ways, including writing all lines to a string and then loading them with a single insertHTML but it still freezes at that point. It freezes with or without a source tag for the audio. This is the line it freeze at, which i'm not sure is relevant but it makes me add some code:

```
document.getElementById('showsect'+k).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',thisqblock);
```

Any ideas or is anybody else running into a similar issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spoke with Apple support. Supposedly this is getting addressed in 12.3, they think it is connected to a security patch.